# How to enable auto-complete-mode when I start R in Emacs?

Tags: r, emacs, autocomplete, ess

In Emacs + ESS, I can start R console by

```
M-x R Return
```

On my system, auto-complete-mode isn't enabled by now. I have to

```
M-x auto-complete-mode Return
```

to enable it.

Is there a way to enable it automaticly?

```
1 OS:       Ubuntu  12.10   64-bit
2 R:        2.15.1
3 Emacs:    24.1.1
4 ESS:      12.04-4
```

Thanks.

Nick

Answer (score 2):

I got the same problem and the following code worked for me.

```
(require 'package)
(add-to-list 'package-archives '("melpa" . "http://melpa.org/packages/") t)
(package-initialize)  ;load and activate packages, including auto-complete
(ac-config-default)
(setq ess-use-auto-complete 'script-only)
;;if not working, use the following instead of (setq ess-use-auto-complete 'script-only)
;;(global-auto-complete-mode t)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set the `ess-use-auto-complete` variable to `t`, either via customize or with the following in your `.emacs` :

```
(setq ess-use-auto-complete t)
```

Comment: Thanks, I've added it to my .emacs; however, it doesn't work, (even after system reboot:(